# python call shell command and check response

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x

Trying to write a function that reads the output of a shell command before making a decision.. For example:

```
6 def getCreds():
  7         global access_key, secret_key, yourName
  8         access_key = raw_input("Enter Access Key: ")
  9         secret_key = raw_input("Enter Secret Key: ")
 10         infoCorrect = raw_input('Is this information correct? (y or n)')
 11         if infoCorrect.lower() == "yes" or infoCorrect.lower() =="y":
 12                 call (["./somecommand -u %s -p %s -flags" % (access_key, secret_key) +     tfdir],shell=True)
 13         else:
```

The output of the shell command is either

```
"You have successfully logged in" 
or
"you cannot log in"
```

So I dont know the right syntax to go :

```
if response = "You have successfully logged in" :
(some action)
elif:
(some action)
```

How to I read the response?

Thanks!

Comment: If you do this regularly, there exist convenience wrappers available. One of them: https://github.com/Chiel92/python-shellout (disclaimer: I wrote it)

Comment: @chowpay, is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Popen()` method defined in `subprocess` and redirect your output to `PIPE`. try this code:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("ls", shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
output,err = p.communicate()
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think output of `shell` command can be returned. You could only check that whether the command is successful or returned an error.

Having said that you could redirect your output to a file and then examine its content.

```
    f = open("outputFile","wb")
    call (["./somecommand -u %s -p %s -flags" % (access_key, secret_key) +     tfdir],shell=True,stdout=f)
```

If you want to avoid writing to file then you may want to look at `StringIO` module.

Comment: is there a better way to do this then instead of using a shell command? What do you suggest?

Comment: better way of doing what?
I mean your question says that you want to get the output of your shell command, so to get a output of shell command you will have to execute,

What exactly your shell command does? there might be way to achieve the same using Python library

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is if there a better way of using the response from a shell command issued via python. This shell command "./somecommand" just send the username and password to web service. If its successful the service returns a response "You have successfully logged in". Using `call` is the only way I know how to issue a shell command in python. But I was wondering if there is a better way to issue this command in python and evaluate the response. Like you said perhaps some Python Library I don't know about. Thanks - python n00b

Comment: popen would be the better way, but still  you will have to redirect op to some file